# Fitting a normal CDF using proportion data

Tags: normal-distribution, proportion, cumulative-distribution-function, curve-fitting, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have the following data (`prop` is like empirical CDF):

```r
td <- data.frame(a = 3:14, prop=c(0, 0, 0.026, 0.143, 0.21, 0.361, 0.535, 
                                  0.719, 0.814, 0.874, 0.950, 0.964))
```

I want to fit a normal CDF using an appropriate mean and standard deviation. How can I find such a mean and a standard deviation value that fits the data above?

```r
mean <- 8.8 # <-- How can I find a best fitting number?
sd <- 2.3 # <-- How can I find a best fitting number?
x <- seq(from = 2, to = 15, by = .1)
cdf <- data.frame(x = x, y = pnorm(q = x, mean = mean,  sd = sd))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = td, aes(x = a, y = prop)) + geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = cdf, aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

The motivation behind this question is to replicate a graph I saw on a book. The book used the same proportions and fitted the normal ogive to the data. It looks like normal ogive fitted so well and I couldn't replicate it. There is no way the author used the raw data because the data is from a 100 years old book and the author's book published about 17 years ago. Here is the graph with its caption:

[image]

*Caption*: "Proportions correct on item 46, plotted against age, with a fitted normal ogive."

Comment: Could you describe the raw data from which you computed the proportions in the `td` data frame?

Comment: Unfortunately, the raw data is not available. `a` represents the age of a child and `prop` represents the percentage of children who correctly answered a question in that age group. I believe the total sample size is about 3,000.

Comment: You need the raw data.  If you have the number of children `n` in each group you can fit a binomial regression model by doing  `glm(prop ~ a, binomial(link="probit"), weight=n)`.  Using the default logit link function instead of the probit would probably make the results easier to interpret (in terms of oddsratios).

Comment: Obviously, having raw data would be great. But, I prefer an answer that uses the given information only, i.e. proportions. I specifically want probit, I'm not interested in any other distribution even if they fit better.

Comment: @JarleTufto My scatterplot data extraction yields raw data as age=[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] and prop=[0.000, 0.002, 0.027, 0.146, 0.218, 0.361, 0.534, 0.721, 0.813, 0.877, 0.951, 0.967]

Comment: @JamesPhillips That's fine but the raw data are counts of number children answering the question correctly and total number children at each age!

Comment: Consider other fits, e.g. a logistic curve.

Comment: I edited the question and added the motivation behind it. As stated, I'm not after a better fit.

Comment: One potential problem I can see is that the data is not an empirical CDF: The first two proportions are 0.

Comment: When you say "total sample size" do you mean across all age groups? Do you have the sample size numbers at the individual ages? This would impact the fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

@JarleTufto is right to suggest a binomial glm with a probit link.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(a = 3:14, prop=c(0, 0, 0.026, 0.143, 0.21, 0.361, 0.535, 
                                   0.719, 0.814, 0.874, 0.950, 0.964))

mod <- glm(prop~a, family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = dat)

xx <- seq(min(dat$a), max(dat$a), length.out = 1000)
pred_frame <- data.frame(a = xx)

pred_frame$fitted <- predict(mod, newdata = pred_frame, type = "response")    

theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = a, y = prop)) + geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(data = pred_frame, aes(x = a, y = fitted), size = 1, colour = "steelblue")
```

[image: glmprobit]

**Original answer**

I mean you could just minimze the sum of squared residuals (least square fit). The best fitting normal distribution has a mean of $8.826$ and a standard deviation of $2.396$. The `R` code:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(a = 3:14, prop=c(0, 0, 0.026, 0.143, 0.21, 0.361, 0.535, 
                                  0.719, 0.814, 0.874, 0.950, 0.964))

foo <- function(parms, x, y) {
  sum((pnorm(x, mean = parms[1], sd = parms[2]) - y)^2)
}

fit <- optim(c(8, 2), fn = foo, x = dat$a, y = dat$prop)

$par
[1] 8.826028 2.396412

xx <- seq(min(dat$a), max(dat$a), length.out = 1000)
fitted <- pnorm(xx, fit$par[1], fit$par[2])

dat2 <- data.frame(a = xx, prop = fitted)

theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = a, y = prop)) + geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(data = dat2, size = 1, colour = "steelblue")
```

[image: CDFfit]

I'm unsure if that makes much sense, though.

Comment: Visually, it better fits better compared the solution I proposed. Much closer to the graph I saw on the book. Still wonder why `fitdist` I proposed did not work as well as this one (visually I mean).

Comment: -1: Surely, even though the underlying count data is unavailable, you would get a more efficient estimate by running a glm taking into account the smaller variance of the proportions that are close to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution. I feel that there might be a better solution/fit and open to other suggestions.

```r
# Create data from proportions, since proportions 
# are accurate to 3 digits, I use 1000:
freq <- td$prop * 1000
freq <- c(freq[1], freq[-1] - freq[-length(freq)])
freq <- rep(x = 3:14, freq)

# Fit normal distribution to the data
library(fitdistrplus)
fitdist(freq, 'norm')
```

Here are the fitted values:

```
Fitting of the distribution ' norm ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
     estimate Std. Error
mean     9.20     0.0698
sd       2.17     0.0493
```

[image]